# Find element in a list that is contained in another class sub-list

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Can you help me to get more performance and more readable code for this piece of code?

```
var prd = new List<Prodotti>();
foreach (var prodotto in db.Prodotti)   
    foreach (var prdId in prdIdx)       
        if (prdId._idProdotto == prodotto.IDProdotto)           
            foreach (var prodottoSeriali in prodotto.AllSerialNumbers)              
                if (prdId.SerialNumber == prodottoSeriali)
                     if (prdId.SerialNumber == prodottoSeriali)                                
                                if (prd.Count(c => c.IDProdotto == prdId._idProdotto) == 1)
                                    prd.Single(c => c.IDProdotto == prdId._idProdotto).SerialNumbers.Add(prdId.SerialNumber);
                                else
                                {
                                    var tmpprd = new Prodotti()
                                    {
                                        IDProdotto = prodotto.IDProdotto,
                                        ...
                                        Descrizione = prodotto.Descrizione,
                                    };
                                       tmpprd.SerialNumbers.Add(prdId.SerialNumber);
                                    prd.Add(tmpprd);
                                }
```

Where db.Prodotti:

```
public partial class Prodotti
{
    public int IDProdotto { get; set; }
    public List<string> SerialNumbers { get; set; }
    public List<string> AllSerialNumbers
    {
        get
        {
          return cfgDb.getSerialByProduct(this.IDProdotto)                   .Select(c => c.SerialNumber).ToList();
        }
```

And prdIdx is a List of:

```
public class cfgProdotti_Noleggio : cfgClass
{
    public int idseriale { get; set; }
    public int _idProdotto { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
```

I have tried to translate it with linq without success:

```
var prd = db.Prodotti.ToList()
Where(t2 => prdIdx.Any(t1 => t1._idProdotto== t2.IDProdotto))
.ToList();
```

Comment: I think you should post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you using EF or this is Linq to Objects?

Comment: db.Prodotti is a generated class of EF

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do a SelectMany on your list of Prodotti to make it one:

```
var l = db.Prodotti.SelectMany(p => p.SerialsNumbers).
```

Then you have a list of SerialNumbers. Just then make an intersect of this list with your prdIdx :

```
var result = prdIdx.Select(m => m.SerialNumber).Intersect(l);
```

The result var is a IEnumerable of common SerialNumber (call .ToList() if you want a list)

Note : untested code

Based on comments :

```
var result = db.Prodotti.Where(p => prdIdx.Any(s => p.SerialsNumbers.Contains(s.SerialNumber));
```

Comment: But I think what OP wants is a collection or `Prodotti`, not serial numbers

Comment: @octavioccl, yes, i need a list of Prodotti filtered by serialnumber assigned in prdIdx list.